# pressKey() action will on invoke TextView.OnEditorActionListener

Tags: android, android-espresso

Given I have a Activity with such kind of setup:

```
EditText edtDeviceName;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    edtDeviceName.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(final TextView v, final int actionId, final KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                // Do something.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to test this using Espresso:

```
onView(withId(R.id.edtDeviceName)).perform(replaceText("DeviceName"));
onView(withId(R.id.edtDeviceName)).perform(pressKey(new EspressoKey.Builder().withKeyCode(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER).build()));
```

Then `TextView.OnEditorActionListener` method `onEditorAction` will not be called.

Is there any special call to make when using Espresso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only work if the View is actually focussed, like this:

```
onView(withId(R.id.edtDeviceName)).perform(click());
```

After that, calls to `pressKey` will end up at the view and cause the action to be triggered.